# Не работает sorted для отправки в телеграм

Tags: python

Есть код, который выводит список новостей в телеграм:

```
import datetime
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from config import token

bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands="all_news")
async def get_all_news(message: types.Message):
    with open("news_dict.json", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        news_dict = json.load(file)

    for k, v in sorted(news_dict.items()):
        news = f"{datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(v['article_date_time'])}\n" \
            f"{v['article_title']}\n" \
            f"{v['article_desc']}\n" \
            f"{v['article_url']}"
        await message.answer(news)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Пример **news_dict**:

```
 "3283072": {
        "article_date_time": 1629140023.0,
        "article_title": "По результ...",
        "article_url": "ссылка",
        "article_desc": "Следова..."
    },
```

Эта строка не работает - **"for k, v in sorted(news_dict.items()):"**
В телеграмме выводит только 1 новость, без нее все в разброс не по дате.

Comment: А что конкретно содержится в news_dict? Пример напишите.

Comment: Если убрать `await message.answer(news)` и добавить `print(news)`, то при вызове команды только одна запись будет в консоли?

Comment: У вас сортировка идет по k, v вместе, а если нужна сортировка по дате, то нужно сортировать по `v['article_date_time']`, т.е. должно быть что-то вроде `for k, v in sorted(news_dict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]['article_date_time']):`. При этом для правильной сортировки там должен быть, например, объект datetime или строка даты в порядке от года до дня (типа "2021-08-17").

Comment: @insolor
Использовал - `sorted(news_dict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]['article_date_time']):`
но вывелись новости только до этого времени **2021-08-16 14:55:11**
Я немного поменял код в самом цикле:
`news = f"{datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(v['article_date_time'])}\n{v['article_title']}\n{v['article_desc']}\n{v['article_url']}"`
Тобишь убрал слэш.

Все пошло, только пару новостей почему-то не запостились(за последний час)
@Tehnorobot Новости: время, название, описание, ссылка

Comment: Покажите пример news_dict в самом вопросе.

Comment: @gil9red Вывелось все четко через `print(news)`
@insolor Пример news_dict:
  `"3283072": {
        "article_date_time": 1629140023.0,
        "article_title": "По результата...",
        "article_url": "https://censo...",
        "article_desc": "Следователи объяв..."
    },`

Comment: Все работает, отпишу как произошло в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Если кому будет полезно, первый момент:

```
    for k, v in sorted(news_dict.items()):
      news = f"{datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(v['article_date_time'])}\n" \
        f"{v['article_title']}\n" \
        f"{v['article_desc']}\n" \
        f"{v['article_url']}"
```

Выводилась одна новость, убрал слеш, пошли все новости:

```
news = f"{datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(v['article_date_time'])}\n{v['article_title']}\n{v['article_desc']}\n{v['article_url']}"
```

Второй момент, новости не шли за последний час, как я понял проблема была лишь во времени. Нужно было просто дольше ждать, под конец посты почему-то шли медленно...

Comment: Не забудьте принять ответ :)